# SQL Server : foreign keys

Tags: sql-server

There are some foreign keys in my list, from a script which returns all foreign key constraints in my database. But when I want to drop some of them it says:

> 'FK_VendorVisitor_Transmittal is not a constraint.
>
> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1134
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

What is happening? How can I remove them from database system tables if they do not really exist?

Comment: This can help: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/12/sql-server-how-to-drop-primary-key-contraint/

Comment: are you talking about s single table keys or all keys in database ?

Comment: Please show us the T-SQL code you used to try to drop this constraint. And also: does the constraint exist? Try `SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE Name = N'FK_VendorVisitor_Transmittal'` - does that return a row??

Comment: "...from a script which returns all foreign key constraints in my database."  Would be helpful to see that script.